# Kendo UI - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery' of undefined

Tags: kendo-ui

Has anyone dealt with *'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery' of undefined'* being thrown from kendo.aspnetmvc.js?

I am using the latest build 2016.1.112, but it was happening on the previous as well 2015.2.1111.  I was hoping the upgrade was going to solve the problem but no luck.

[image: Console message]
[image: Source code]

Comment: Anyone managed to solve this one? I have the same problem.

Comment: I had the same problem but with kendo.draganddrop.js. It appears I had failed to include the correct js files though and in the correct order. Maybe try to look that up. It might solve your problem too. @Fabio S.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the order of the JS files are in correct Order.Below is the order i used to fix the bug i got.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.all.min.js</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
```

Initially the script file **kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js** was before **kendo.all.min.js**, which was the cause of the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery' of undefined"